# Filtering multiple value with multiple key in json array using lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter, lodash

i have a dynamic data each time there could be dynamically different key value pair to be filtered in different data. how can we filter it with multiple key,value in lodash. i was using its filter function but result is not achievable.

example data:

```
    var data = [ {
  "VOTER" : 1012,
  "PARTY" : "REPUBLICAN",
  "PRECINCT" : 2408,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 51,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1013,
  "PARTY" : "REPUBLICAN",
  "PRECINCT" : 2411,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1014,
  "PARTY" : "DEMOCRAT",
  "PRECINCT" : 2424,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1015,
  "PARTY" : "DEMOCRAT",
  "PRECINCT" : 2418,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
    },{
  "VOTER" : 1109,
  "PARTY" : "AMERICAN INDEP",
  "PRECINCT" : 2404,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 34,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
},{
  "VOTER" : 1111,
  "PARTY" : "DECLINED",
  "PRECINCT" : 2414,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 34,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
}

]
```

and filter object is:

```
var filterby = {"PARTY":["REPUBLICAN","DEMOCRAT"],"BALLOT_STATUS":["PERM","POLL"]}
```

Filter function from lodash:

```
var filtered_data = _.filter(data, filterby);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use plain Javascript and iterate the keys of the filterBy and the values.

```js
var data = [{ VOTER: 1012, PARTY: "REPUBLICAN", PRECINCT: 2408, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 51, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1013, PARTY: "REPUBLICAN", PRECINCT: 2411, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1014, PARTY: "DEMOCRAT", PRECINCT: 2424, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1015, PARTY: "DEMOCRAT", PRECINCT: 2418, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }, { VOTER: 1109, PARTY: "AMERICAN INDEP", PRECINCT: 2404, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 34, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }, { VOTER: 1111, PARTY: "DECLINED", PRECINCT: 2414, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 34, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }],
    filterBy = { PARTY: ["REPUBLICAN", "DEMOCRAT"], BALLOT_STATUS: ["PERM", "POLL"] },
    result = data.filter(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(filterBy).every(function (k) {
            return filterBy[k].some(function (f) {
                return o[k] === f;
            });
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var data = [{ VOTER: 1012, PARTY: "REPUBLICAN", PRECINCT: 2408, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 51, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1013, PARTY: "REPUBLICAN", PRECINCT: 2411, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1014, PARTY: "DEMOCRAT", PRECINCT: 2424, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "PERM" }, { VOTER: 1015, PARTY: "DEMOCRAT", PRECINCT: 2418, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 50, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }, { VOTER: 1109, PARTY: "AMERICAN INDEP", PRECINCT: 2404, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 34, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }, { VOTER: 1111, PARTY: "DECLINED", PRECINCT: 2414, AGE_GROUP: "71 +", LAST_VOTED: "08/2006", YEARS_REG: 34, BALLOT_STATUS: "POLL" }],
    filterBy = { PARTY: ["REPUBLICAN", "DEMOCRAT"], BALLOT_STATUS: ["PERM", "POLL"] },
    result = data.filter(o => Object.keys(filterBy).every(k => filterBy[k].some(f => o[k] === f)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hello i know its too late to ask but i have using your code for filter but there was an error like .some is not a function, can you please help with this

Comment: @RahulDudharejiya, you need the same object structure for `filterBy` like above with properties and arrays as value, because you need the method from `Array` prototype. please add an example of the taken object.

Comment: @NinaScholz hi, its too late but how can it be modified if the Json array is nested one. here i want to filter using voter and statusVal. eg : [ {
  "VOTER" : 1012,
  "PARTY" : "REPUBLICAN",
  "PRECINCT" : 2408,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 51,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
  "vehicleStatusHistory": {
      "id": 721,
      "Ind": "Y",
      "status": {
        "StatusId": 3,
        "StatusVal": "In-Transit"
      }
    },
}
]

Comment: it's quite a different format. please ask a new question along with wanted result and code, you tried.

Comment: Really worth solution .

Comment: @NinaScholz there is a lot of javascript/ES6 dexterity bundled up in your answer, it helped me a ton.  Thank you.  A few comments interspersed at each nested level would have made it sink in faster for me.

Answer (score 4):

`_.filter` method doesn't allow you to specify multiple options for filtering. Try with passing custom filter function:

```
_.filter(data, function (item) {
  return ['REPUBLICAN', 'DEMOCRAT'].indexOf(item.PARTY) >= 0
      && ['PERM', 'POLL'].indexOf(item.BALLOT_STATUS) >= 0
})
```

Comment: Thanks @hsz, for your answer but filterby will be dynamic i will not know there could be 2 as well 3 or 5 key value pair for example there could be:
var filterby = {"PARTY":["REPUBLICAN","DEMOCRAT"],"BALLOT_STATUS":["PERM","POLL"],"VOTER":"1014"}

Comment: So use variables instead.

Comment: how can you please guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

The `_.filter` function which iterates over elements of collection which is passes on first parameter in your case it's `data` and second parameter should be a function which is invoked per iteration for more info see [Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter).

For this in your example you can use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Please find below snippet for more info.

Change your `filterby` var as below

```
var filterby = (m) => { return m => m.PARTY == "REPUBLICAN" || m.PARTY == "DEMOCRAT" && m.BALLOT_STATUS == "PERM" || m.BALLOT_STATUS == "POLL"  };
```

```js
var data = [ {
  "VOTER" : 1012,
  "PARTY" : "REPUBLICAN",
  "PRECINCT" : 2408,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 51,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1013,
  "PARTY" : "REPUBLICAN",
  "PRECINCT" : 2411,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1014,
  "PARTY" : "DEMOCRAT",
  "PRECINCT" : 2424,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "PERM"
}, {
  "VOTER" : 1015,
  "PARTY" : "DEMOCRAT",
  "PRECINCT" : 2418,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 50,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
    },{
  "VOTER" : 1109,
  "PARTY" : "AMERICAN INDEP",
  "PRECINCT" : 2404,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 34,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
},{
  "VOTER" : 1111,
  "PARTY" : "DECLINED",
  "PRECINCT" : 2414,
  "AGE_GROUP" : "71 +",
  "LAST_VOTED" : "08/2006",
  "YEARS_REG" : 34,
  "BALLOT_STATUS" : "POLL"
}

]



//var filterby = {"PARTY":["REPUBLICAN","DEMOCRAT"],"BALLOT_STATUS":["PERM","POLL"]}

var filterby = (m) => { return m => m.PARTY == "REPUBLICAN" || m.PARTY == "DEMOCRAT" && m.BALLOT_STATUS == "PERM" || m.BALLOT_STATUS == "POLL"  };


var filtered_data = _.filter(data, filterby);
console.log(filtered_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```