# Lodash multiple key with multiple array of values filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, lodash

I'm trying to filtering multidimensional object using lodash filter object . Below are my sample object to filter data.

```
    {
  "0": {
    "details": {
      "rating": 2.5,
      "amenities": {
        "airConditioning": true,
      },
    },
    "rates": {
      "packages": [
        {
          "refundable": "Yes",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
  "1": {
    "details": {
      "rating": 3,
      "amenities": {
        "airConditioning": false,
      },
    },
    "rates": {
      "packages": [
        {
          "refundable": "Yes",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
  "2": {
    "details": {
      "rating": 2,
      "amenities": {
        "airConditioning": true,
      },
    },
    "rates": {
      "packages": [
        {
          "refundable": "No",
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

I have tried

```
    console.log(_.filter( data, { 'details.rating': '2', 'details.rating': '3' } ));

_.filter(data, function (item) {
  return ['2', '3'].indexOf(item.details.rating) >= 0
})
```

And followed this too [Filtering multiple value with multiple key in json array using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236312/filtering-multiple-value-with-multiple-key-in-json-array-using-lodash)

nothing working

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has extra `{` before the key `"1"` and `"2"`. So remove that and it will work.

```js
    var data = {
      "0": {
        "details": {
          "rating": 2.5,
          "amenities": {
            "airConditioning": true,
          },
        },
        "rates": {
          "packages": [
            {
              "refundable": "Yes",
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      
      "1": {
        "details": {
          "rating": 3,
          "amenities": {
            "airConditioning": false,
          },
        },
        "rates": {
          "packages": [
            {
              "refundable": "Yes",
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "details": {
          "rating": 2,
          "amenities": {
            "airConditioning": true,
          },
        },
        "rates": {
          "packages": [
            {
              "refundable": "No",
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    };
    var result = _.filter(data, (item) => {
      return [2, 3].indexOf(item.details.rating) >= 0
    });
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the array elements inside the filter `[2, 3]`. They are integer type as `item.details.rating` is an integer.

Comment: The first levela array ratings filtering is working , but the amenities sub object filtering is not working.I m trying to filter amenities airconditioing true set array of obejct i have used _some(item.details.amentities,{airConditioning:true}) ..but its return false

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying

Comment: I mean i'm trying to filter this attribute " item.details.amenities " => {airConditioning:true}.